# Android work with Custom map

Tags: android, google-maps, svg, location

I want to Develop a project where it will work with custom map. I have a image in SVG format which is a campus image. I want to get the user current location and show the path of user selected location.

I can't understand where to start. How it worked. I know how to work with Google Map.

Very less tutorials are available in web. So I am unable to get sufficient help from Google.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get user location using .svg image. Vector images can be use as a map marker, icon, symbol or image to a polyline.

If you want to get current location, use  [FusedLocationProviderApi](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location#request_runtime_permissions). [FusedLocationProviderApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi) provides improved location finding and power usage and is used by the "My Location" blue dot.

To show path selected location, use Google Maps Android API to expose intents that you can to launch Google Maps in display. It allows you to display map in a specified location and zoom level, show directions, search for a location and display them on a map. Directions can be returned in driving, walking or bicycling.

Here's a sample demo app which discuss how to get current location and show direction to selected location: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/MyLocationDemoActivity.java

Start your poject by following steps listed in Official Google Documentation for Maps Android API. Here is the link : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start#step_3_create_a_google_maps_project

Comment: Thanks for your answar. Let me try :)